# Fail to upload sketch when Arduino Nano is connected to breakout board

Tags: arduino-nano, uploading

When I upload a sketch from Arduino IDE to my Arduino Nano (not yet connected to breakout board) via USB, it works. I can then plug the Nano back to the breakout board and let it do its thing.

However, if the same Nano is already connected to the breakout board (which is in turn connected to some other things), and I try to upload a sketch via USB, it does not work.

The error message is:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

Sketch uses 3844 bytes (12%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.

Global variables use 204 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1844 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

What's wrong? How do I solve it?

Comment: What breakout board do you have? Does it use the serial interface? Upload is done via serial. So if you block the serial interface with some other device, you cannot upload

Comment: Thanks chrisl

I think it's this one: https://www.jvzdigitalsourcing.com/products/arduino-nano-breakout-board

I think it's supposed to work with serial interface though, because the school provided all the hardware I'm using (it's for a course), and one of the things we need to do in this course is to control some motors via serial interface.

Comment: Have you pins 0 and 1 connected to anything?

Comment: Nope, 0 and 1 not connected to anything

Comment: !!!! I realised the RXN and TXN pins connecting to the bluetooth module are 0 and 1 pins! Oh god!

Comment: I unplugged them and now it's okay :) Thanks!